# Newman Modularity

Tags: modularity

I have computed a Newman modularity for a graph which is Q = 0.67 but I do not know what this value states? Can anyone explain the range of of Q that is from [0;1]? In other words: what does Q = 0.67 mean concretely?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Q ranges from -1 to 1, with 1 meaning optimal modularity. However, the maximum achievable modularity for a given graph isn't necessarily 1 but possibly lower, depending on its particular structure, so strictly speaking the values are only meaningful in relation to the Q values for other assignments on the same graph. Less strictly speaking, assignments with Q values above 0.3 are typically considered a successfully identified cluster structure, even though that's more of a heuristic and I'm not even sure where I read that.

Comment: I also have never seen that magic number of 0.3 justified. But I've seen it appear in Newman's papers, for example, on page 2 of [Clauset, Newman and Moore 2004](http://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.70.066111), they state "in practice it is found that a value above about 0.3 is a good indicator of significant community structure in a network." Vague to say the least! And I think it is untrue on smaller networks where the maximum possible Q is lower.

Comment: Note that depending on the modularity formula, modularity might also be in the range [-0.5, 1], e.g. see the paper [On Modularity Clustering](https://kops.uni-konstanz.de/bitstream/handle/123456789/5853/modularity.pdf) with a proof at the beginning of chapter III.